1995 Suburban Stalls and No start - Injectors not firing consistently and strange oil readings
My 1995 Suburban died while running at 45mph.  I believe the check gauges light was on and I couldn't see oil on the dipstick (it was dark and I was using a flashlight), but when I returned in the morning the dipstick showed full oil (I had recently done an oil change). I was able to get it started but it had no power and was racing up and down with rpms and nearly stalling so I just drove it half a mile to my neighbor's driveway so I can walk over with tools. I replaced the fuel filter and had good pressure at the filter throughout attempted start but it wouldn't start.  I then replaced cap, rotor, and ignition control module and it started but ran rough under eve a little bit of throttle.  Fuel injectors seemed ok when cranking or connected to a 9v battery, but I decided to replace them. New injectors work perfectly with a 9v battery but only sprayed once or twice when we attempted to start the engine. The other weird thing is that the injector connectors consistently show almost 9 volts when cranking so it seems like power is getting to the injectors. A couple other things that might be relevant: 1. we have a newly rebuilt tranny, and the vehicle seemed more sluggish after getting it back; 2 when we stop cranking fuel, seems to spray out of somewhere in the throttle body (is this expected or is this a designed pressure release?).  Any ideas what is going on?

This is using a throttle body fuel injection, correct? 350 V8? And no, it should not be spewing fuel inside the throttle body after you finish cranking, which leads me to believe it is dumping excess fuel and causing a near flooded condition. If you pull the sparkplugs, do they look wet at all?

Yes that's the right engine.  I will check the spark plugs

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Had to go out of town but I've done some more testing.  At this point we now have a no spark condition at the coil.  Coil resistances seems ok based on my Haynes manual although I haven't been able to get the exact spec on the secondary coil.  We do get 12v at the coil from the starter circuit when the key is turned to run.  I am planning to test the pick up coil resistance tomorrow.  But at this point it seems like we either have 1) a bad distributor pickup coil, 2) a bad coil, 3) a bad PCM, or 4) bad ground somewhere.  Am I missing any other issues to investigate?

Also, at this point my working theory for the spewing of fuel is that unburnt fuel was being forced back out the intake valves into the throttle body, although it's unclear to me why the unburnt mixture wouldn't just go out the exhaust valves.

I think your list of things to test is a good one. Your idea that gas is being pushed back up into the intake is not really feasible, so I would discount it completely. The engine, for all intents and purposes, is an air pump. As long as everything is timed correctly (and no reason to believe it isn't), there's only one direction things are going to move, in through the intake, to the cylinder, then out the exhaust. It just doesn't flow the other way.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Well I did notice today that in spite of labeling everything, I somehow mixed up the wires for the 4 and 6 cylinders, but I can't think of how that could cause a no spark situation.  I just tested the pickup coil and its resistance is in spec.  People say the a lot of the replacement ignition control modules have problems so I suppose my new one could have died.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It just started and ran.  The only thing I can think that is different is that when I went to test the distributor pick up coil, I accidentally pulled the wires out of the connector so I had to remove the connector and re install the wires.  Possibly the wires were already loose in the connector and were making a bad connection with the ignition control module.  The only other option is a bad ground somewhere that happens to be working now but could die anytime.
